# ReactViewGroup not displayed, too large to fit software layout

Tags: android, react-native

The problem is pretty simple, still I can't figure out why it happens. I'd need some good **Android and/or React Native developers**.
I have a settings page in my application which renders 4 boxes (depending content of the settings, like user password, email modification...) and one of them has a bit much more content than the others.

The problem seems to only occur on **Android 7.0** (testing with a real device, **Honor 8**) and it works well on One Plus 6 (8.1) and a Xiaomi (I don't know which one, running 7.1)
As long as I want to display all the content of the box, it will just not render to the screen, but still takes the height needed in the ScrollView to be displayed (see the screens)
At first, I didn't understand why, because no error was triggered, I decided to check the logCats and I got this error :

*View: ReactViewGroup not displayed because it is too large to fit into a software layer (or drawing cache), needs 8636760 bytes, only 8294400 available*

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzKGI.jpg)

So I tried multiple things:

**set android:hardwareAccelerated="false"** in the *AndroidManifest*, **this solution works** BUT the app is quite laggy when you scroll, and all is a bit slowed down (I would love to avoid this)

**Delete some components** from the render, **which also works**, but... obviously, I want all my content in this box

I tried to understand which component takes a lot of space (in bytes) by adding/deleting the components in the view and referring to the logCat, seems like ZestInput takes quite a lot, as custom components for Toggles, and Checkboxes (I also tried with native TextInput to compare with our custom input, the result was not that far... they bot take a lot of space)

```
render() {
    const {
      textStyle,
      titleTextStyle,
      subtleText,
      boxStyle,
      marginLarge,
      marginSmall,
      marginLeft,
      buttonStyle,
    } = styles;
const { isUpdating, newMail } = this.state;
const { user, emailEdition } = this.props;

const emailTranslation =
  newMail === ''
    ? translations.t('ADD_EMAIL')
    : translations.t('CHANGE_EMAIL');

return (
  <MCollapsableBox
    style={boxStyle}
    headerText={translations.t('APPLICATION_SETTINGS')}
  >
    <View>
      <Text style={[titleTextStyle, marginLarge]}>
        {translations.t('PARAMETERS_CHOOSE_LANGUAGE')}
      </Text>

      {(newMail === '' || emailEdition) && (
        <View>
          <Separation />
          <Text style={[titleTextStyle, marginLarge]}>
            {translations.t('EMAIL')}
          </Text>
          <ZestInput
            //ref={ref => (this.inputRef = ref)}
            placeholder={emailTranslation}
            onChangeText={this.changeMailAddress}
            value={newMail}
          />
          {user.tmpEmail !== '' && (
            <View>
              <Text style={[textStyle, marginSmall]}>
                {translations.t('CURRENT_TMP_MAIL')}
              </Text>
              <Text style={[textStyle, marginLeft]}>{user.tmpEmail}</Text>
              <Text style={[subtleText, marginLeft]}>
                {translations.t('EMAIL_NEEDS_VALIDATION')}
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <PrimaryButton
            onPress={this.onChangeEmail}
            style={buttonStyle}
            isLoading={isUpdating}
            disabled={!this.checkIsEmail(newMail)}
          >
            {emailTranslation}
          </PrimaryButton>
        </View>
      )}

      <Separation />
      <Text style={[titleTextStyle]}>
        {translations.t('PARAMETERS_VISIBILITY')}
      </Text>
      {_.map(this.state.privacyOptions, (value, key) => {
        return (
          <TitledTextToggle
            title={value.text}
            options={value.options}
            onPress={this.toggleChanged}
            key={key}
            id={key}
          />
        );
      })}
      <Separation />
      <Text style={[titleTextStyle, marginSmall]}>
        {translations.t('MOOD_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS')}
      </Text>
      <Text style={[textStyle, marginLarge]}>
        {translations.t('MOOD_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS_TEXT')}
      </Text>
      <CheckboxList
        onPress={this.onPressCheckbox}
        options={this.state.moodNotification}
      />
      <PrimaryButton
        onPress={this.onSave}
        style={buttonStyle}
        isLoading={isUpdating}
      >
        {translations.t('SAVE')}
      </PrimaryButton>
    </View>
  </MCollapsableBox>
);
```

}

This is what I expect

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXxkZ.jpg)

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF6Li.jpg)

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCnti.jpg)

Comment: did you try by changing the wrapping element from <View> to <ScrollView> ?

Comment: @DhavalChheda I succeeded to debug thanks to your answer, the little detail is that the ScrollView is in a children of MCollapsableBox (which is called BoxContent) who takes children directly from MCollapsableBox